# Google's radarsearch API results

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to geolocate all the businesses related to a keyword in my city using, first, the radarsearch API in order to retrieve the Place ID and later using the Places API to get more information of each Place ID (such as the name, or the formatted address).

In my first approach I splitted my city in 9 circumferences, each one with radius 22km and avoiding rural zones, where there's no supposed to be a business. This way I obtained (once removing duplicated results, due to the circumferences overlapping) approximately 150 businesses. This result is not reliable because the official webpage of the company asserts there are 245.

In order to retrieve ALL the businesses, I split my city in circumferences of radius 10km. Therefore with approx 50 pairs of coordinates I fill the city, including now all zones, both rural and non-rural. Now, surprisingly I obtain only 81 businesses! How can this be possible?

I'm storing all the information in separated dictionaries and I noticed the amount of data of each dictionary increases with the increasing of the radius and is always the same (for a fixed radius).

Now, apart from the previous question, is there any way to limit the amount of results each request yields?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
dict1 = {}
radius=20000 
keyword='keyworkd'
key=YOUR_API_KEY
url_base="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?"
list_dicts = []
for i,(lo, la) in enumerate(zip(lon_txt,lat_txt)):
    url=url_base+'location='+str(lo)+','+str(la)+'&radius='+str(radius)+'&keyword='+keyword+'&key='+key
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    table = json.load(response)
    if table['status']=='OK':
        for j,line in enumerate(table['results']):
            temp = {j : line['place_id']}
            dict1.update(temp)
        list_dicts.append(dict1)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this problem.

The thing was the dict initialization must be done in each loop iteration. Now it stores all the information and I retrieve what I wanted from the beginning.

```
dict1 = {}
radius=20000 
keyword='keyworkd'
key=YOUR_API_KEY
url_base="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?"
list_dicts = []
for i,(lo, la) in enumerate(zip(lon_txt,lat_txt)):
    url=url_base+'location='+str(lo)+','+str(la)+'&radius='+str(radius)+'&keyword='+keyword+'&key='+key
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    table = json.load(response)
    if table['status']=='OK':
        for j,line in enumerate(table['results']):
            temp = {j : line['place_id']}
            dict1.update(temp)
        list_dicts.append(dict1)
        dict1 = {}
    else:
        pass
```